# NSSound working, but not initialized or allocated..

Tags: objective-c, memory, object, methods, memory-management

I have a simple program that plays a song. It's in the inherited awakeFromNib method. So..

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
NSSound *song = [NSSound soundNamed:@"MyTune.mp3"];
[song play];
}
```

My question is, why does this work. How come I don't have to do this

```
NSSound *song = [[NSSound alloc]init];
song = [NSSound soundNamed:@"MyTune.mp3"];
[song play];
}
```

It also seems to work with strings too.. I have a NSTextView variable set up and I can do the following

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello there!"];
[myTextVariable insertText:str];
}
```

Why didn't I have to alloc and init the objects.. I am so lost.. 
Please help.

Comment: Anyone? I'm just having a hard time understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of Apple's classes have helper functions, declared at the class level which do the alloc and init for you, inside the helper function. They return a ready to use object.  You can tell if yu see the doc for the method and it says something like "Returns the NSSound instance associated with a given name."

Your first example is therefore good code:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
NSSound *song = [NSSound soundNamed:@"MyTune.mp3"];
[song play];
}
```

Your second example leaks memory because you alloc and then overwrite your pointer with a new object returned by `[NSSound soundNamed:@"MyTune.mp3"]`:

```
  -(void)awakeFromNib {

    // Create an NSSound object in memory and store the address in song.
    NSSound *song = [[NSSound alloc]init]; 

    // If you don't want a memory leak this is your last chance to [song release]

    // Create a NSSound object using a helper function and place its address 
    // in song, over writing the previous address.
    song = [NSSound soundNamed:@"MyTune.mp3"];

    // We now lost track of the first NSSound object and can't release it because 
    // we overwrote the address.

    [song play];
    }
```

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can see that this method is doing the `alloc` and `init` inside it and returning the instance to you:

**soundNamed**:

Returns the NSSound instance associated with a given name.

**+ (id)soundNamed:(NSString *)soundName**

**Parameters**

*soundName*
Name that identifies sound data.

**Return Value**

NSSound instance initialized with the sound data identified by soundName.

Comment: Ok, so say on my second example I include 

[song release];


would it be the same thing?

Comment: You don't release it since you didn't allocate it. When you use a helper function, Apple's code will control the releasing for you. It does this because *it* allocated it.

Comment: I think I didn't get your meaning. If you are asking about inserting a release between lines 2 and 3 in the second example, then yes. It would be functionally the same as the first example but a waste of CPU cycles and coding.

Comment: Thank's Richard, yes that is what I was asking. Basically, If I inserted [song release]; AFTER [song play]; then it would take care of the leak...

Comment: Also, I did not know about the helper function. Is there an easy way to tell which Classes have it?

Comment: Please see my edited answer. If you wait till after [song play] you can't undo the memory leak in the second example.  Checking the documentation is best.  Anytime you are using a class level method from Apple you can check the doc to see it it creates the object for you. You get a feel for it after a short time.

Comment: Thank you. Also, I'm understanding what you wrote in the second example. I get it now, but what isn't falling into place in my head is  my first example. Where exactly is the alloc/ init part occurring? All I see is  NSSound (class) *song (pointer to object) and then the assignment. That's what I was trying to get at.

I ask because I always thought to create an object my self I had to do alloc on the class for memory space and init on the object for it to be used. In the first example im missing where this occurs.

Comment: You don't have to create an object yourself; you are just storing a pointer to the object that has already been created for you through the internal workings of soundNamed.

Comment: I updated the answer again to include showing how you can tell that the object is being created for you.

Comment: I see.Really, I can't thank you enough, you both solved my headache.